# NPM Error old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of NPM

Tags: angular, angular9, package-lock.json, ng-upgrade

`package-lock.json` creating problem for upgrading Angular 9 to 10

How can I create a fresh `package-lock.json` file and update Angular 9 to 10?

I want to update Angular 9 to 10 and want to solve this `package-lock.json` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is related to your node version.

Something you can do is change the version according to this compatibility table https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3.

Then delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and run "npm i".

It should work, let me know